# Removing .html/.php from url with apache conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

I managed to remove the .extension via the htaccess file, but I was wondering if this is possible through the apache2.conf or some other file without using the .htaccess file.

Exp.

```
example.com/example
```

instead of

```
example.com/example.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in Apache conf file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Those don't work with the apache conf. It gives me an error. Aren't those rules for the .htaccess?